# Laravel And AWS RDS Migration Cannot Connect Database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Hi I am new to laravel in my app when i connecting database i got following error

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

```
public function createConnection($dsn, array $config, array $options)
{
$username = array_get($config, 'username');
$password = array_get($config, 'password');
**return new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);**
}
 'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'HOST NAME',
        'port'      => '3306',
        'database'  => 'DBNAME',
        'username'  => 'DBUSER',
        'password'  => 'DBPASSWORD',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => 'vox_',
    ),
```

Comment: Please post the relevant database config from `app/config/database.php` (excluding the password of course).

Comment: I have updated db details

Comment: Are you able to connect using a remote client (like MySQL Workbench) to that database using your credentials?

Answer (score 1):

This might be pretty obvious, but

```
 'host'      => 'HOST NAME',
        'port'      => '3306',
        'database'  => 'DBNAME',
        'username'  => 'DBUSER',
        'password'  => 'DBPASSWORD',
```

those are set to strings HOST NAME, DBNAME, etc. hardcode your DB credentials and see if it works.

Comment: I have changed No Luck

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the host name with an IP address